# checking response from php script C++

Tags: php, c++

im trying to get the salt from a table in my database and return the value to my C++ application so i can encrypt the users password and match vs database. im running into some trouble

```
$state = $this->con->prepare("SELECT salt FROM Login WHERE user = ?");
$state->bind_param("s", $this->SanatizeString($this->GetValue('salt')));
$state->execute();
$result = $state->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$salt = $row['salt'];

echo $this->Crypto(json_encode(array("response" => $salt), false);
```

this is what im doing in the script to return the salt.
and in the application im doing

```
salt = result["response"].get<std::string>().c_str();
```

but json is giving me a weird error

[image]

Comment: What is `$this->Crypto()`? Is the C++ code decrypting it before trying to parse the JSON?

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).